# Why will I have C++ unknown reference link error on the application program but not the library in linux

Tags: c++, linux

Now I am building a C++ dynamic library `libabc.so`  and an application `test` based on this library in linux.   `libabc.so` will invoke boost dynamic library `libboost.so`. I can compile `libabc.so` very well, and no errors can be found. If I use `ldd` command on `libabc.so`, I can easily observe that this library has a dependency on `libboost.so`. However, when I compile the application program `test`, I have the following link error:

```
abc.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::copy_option, boost::system::error_code*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I do not know where the problem comes from. When I compile `test` program, I am sure that I link it with both `libabc.so` and `libboost.so`.  I also changed the sequence of `libabc.so` and `libboost.so` when linking just to make sure that the right library sequence is given. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I think you also need `boost_system`, i.e. `-lboost_system`.

Comment: What is `boost.so`? This is not a normal Linux library name (no "lib" prefix) and not a normal boost library name (boost normally comes packaged as many small shared libraries, not one big library). It's not illegal but unusual. On my system, the function in question is in `libbost_filesystem.so` (and `libbost_filesystem-mt.so`).

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for your comments. I build the whole boost library and put them in a single library, which is called libboost.so.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for the comments, and I build the whole boost library and assemble them into a single library, which is called libboost.so. Sorry, I called it boost.so in my previous post. I have changed it.

Comment: You can check whether your library has the function by doing `nm -CD libboost.so | grep boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file`.

Comment: @n.m. I did as you suggested. It seems that libboost.so has this function: 0039dd5b T boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::copy_option::enum_type, boost::system::error_code*)

Comment: @n.m. However, when I run nm -CD libabc.so | grep boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file. Here is the output: U boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::copy_option, boost::system::error_code*).

Comment: You have two different functions. The one that's defined in libboost boost::filesystem::copy_option::enum_type, and the one that is undefined in libabc takes boost::filesystem::copy_option. Different boost versions?

Comment: @n.m. thanks for your comments. I use the same boost library. I searched and found the following post http://www.ridgesolutions.ie/index.php/2013/05/30/boost-link-error-undefined-reference-to-boostfilesystemdetailcopy_file/ may be helpful. I will try and see whether it can work.

Comment: Yes, if you use c++11, you have to compile boost with -std=c++11. Really annoying.

Comment: @n.m. Now it works, and I think the problem comes from the fact that libabc.so and libboost.so define different functions, which you mentioned in your previous comments. If you like, could you make it the right answer to this post so that others can learn from my question? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function in question is defined to take different arguments, depending on whether the programis compiled as C++03 or C++11.

```
void boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::copy_option::enum_type, boost::system::error_code*) // pre-C++11

void boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::copy_option, boost::system::error_code*) // C++11
```

In my opinion this is a Boost bug.

Consequently, if this function is used in a program, then both Boost and the program must be compiled with C++11 support, or both without. Otherwise the program will fail at the linking stage.

Shared libraries in Linux are normally allowed to have unresolved references, this doesn't cause their linking to fail.